# Caching in Apache 2.2 & Tomcat 7.0

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, apache-1.3

From what I understand there are three types of caching,

1. Disk cache on Apache Server `httpd.conf`
2. Memory cache on Apache Server `httpd.conf`
3. Tomcat cache on Tomcat 7.0 (Configuring `context.xml`)

Between all the three types of caching which is the faster and the least resource intensive?

What is the difference between Apache caching and tomcat cache?

When should I use tomcat caching and apache caching? Or can I run both in my cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about what caching you need/want to use. It is about the type and requirements of your web application. Apache can run php/perl code, but tomcat is used to run java/jsp code.

As for the caching question, the memory caching is for sure much faster than any disk caching.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up. However, I have a few more clarification. I wish to setup apache (memory caching) for my load balancer, do I only need to setup in the (httpd.conf) file? That is the only settings I need to do right?

Answer (score 1):

It probably depending on what you are caching. If your app server is mostly generated static pages for anonymous visitors you should probably consider external caching options like Varnish.